# "Undefined variable: array" Error In Displaying Post Tag

Tags: array, conditional-tags

I'm trying to display the post tags through a widget, I've following codes and  getting error "Undefined variable: array":

```
    if ( $instance['stats_tag']['category'] ) {         
        $posttags = get_the_tags();
        if ($posttags) {
           $array = array();
            foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            $link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
              $array[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag" itemprop="keywords">' . $tag->name . '</a>';

        }   
    }   
    if ( $stats != '' ) {
        $stats[] =  '<span class="the-day-tags">' . implode(', ', (array)$array). '</span>' ;
    }
```

Can anyone help me to fix the issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not getting into your first if - And therefore the $array is not defined, since you do it in that condition and also use it if $stats is not empty - Either define the $array before the
if($instance) or find another way :-D 
so something like this, will get you on the right track

```
$array = array();
if ( $instance['stats_tag']['category'] ) {         
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {

        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
        $link = get_tag_link($tag->term_id);
          $array[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $link ) . '" rel="tag" itemprop="keywords">' . $tag->name . '</a>';

    }   
} 
if ( $stats != '' ) {
    $stats[] =  '<span class="the-day-tags">' . implode(', ', (array)$array). '</span>' ;
}
```

Comment: Also, to not confuse yourself later, you should maybe start naming your variables more specific names, like $arrayOfLinks = array();

Comment: Thanks  @Stender, now error is fixed, but getting so confusing issue again, post tags are displayed in home page but not in custom page, what's causing it? i'm getting confused.